# Restarting host from docker container

Tags: docker

As the title indicates, is it possible to restart the host from a container? I have a docker container running with systemd as described [here](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/05/05/running-systemd-within-docker-container/) and started as:

```
$ docker run -privileged --net host -ti -d -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro <image_name>
```

Once I issue the `systemctl reboot` command, I see:

```
# systemctl reboot
[root@dhcp-40-115 /]# 
[3]+  Stopped
```

The host doesn't reboot. However, I see `[1915595.016950] systemd-journald[17]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).` on host's kernel buffer.

**Use case:**

I am experimenting with running the [restraint test harness](http://restraint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in a container and some of the tests reboot the host and hence if this is possible to do from a container, the tests can run unchanged.

**Update**

As I mention in my answer:

> There is a detail I missed in my question above which is once I have
>   systemd running in the container itself, the systemctl reboot is
>   (roughly saying) connecting to systemd on the container itself which
>   is not what I want.

The accepted answer has the advantage that it is not dependent on the host and the container distro be have compatible `systemd`. However, on a setup where they are, my answer is what I think is a more acceptable one, since you can just use the usual `reboot` command.

Other init systems such as `upstart` is untested.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to send sysrq commands to the host mounting `/proc/sysrq-trigger` as a volume.

This booted the host.

```
docker-server# docker run -i -t -v /proc/sysrq-trigger:/sysrq centos bash
docker-container# echo b > /sysrq
```

You can set a bit-mask permission on `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` on the host to only allow eg, sync the disks and boot. More information about this at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key but something like this (untested) should set those permissions:

```
echo 144 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

Also remember to add `kernel.sysrq = 144` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` to have it saved over reboots.

Comment: Looks promising, thanks! However, for now something which worked for me is posted as answer.

Comment: Tested so far: Fedora container on a Fedora host, Ubuntu container on a Fedora host. Accepting this as the answer since, it is not dependent on the container and the host OS init systems to be the same/compatible. Very nice tip!

Comment: This might work nicely, but beware that `echo b > /sysrq`
"Will immediately reboot the system without syncing or unmounting your disks."
See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html#what-are-the-command-keys

Comment: @orzechow then you can echo s > /sysrq first

Comment: @Softlion exactly!

Answer (score 8):

There is a detail I missed in my question above which is once I have `systemd` running in the container itself, the `systemctl reboot` is (roughly saying) connecting to `systemd` on the container itself which is not what I want.

On the hint of a colleague, here is what I did on a "stock" fedora image (nothing special in it):

```
$ docker run -ti -v /run/systemd:/run/systemd fedora /bin/bash
```

Then in the container:

```
bash-4.2# systemctl status docker
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2014-07-01 04:57:22 UTC; 2 weeks 0 days ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.io
 Main PID: 2589
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
```

Here, the container is able to access `systemd` on the host. Then, issuing a `reboot` command actually reboots the host:

```
bash-4.2# reboot
```

Thus, it is possible to reboot the host from the container.

The point to note here is that the host is running Fedora 20 and so is the container. If the host was a different distro not running `systemd`, this would not be possible. Generally speaking, if the host and the container are running distros which are not running systemd or incompatible versions of systemd, this will not work.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, this works, and so does mounting only /run/dbus. But I have to say, I like 59634's solution more than giving all of dbus to a container. Also, you only need to mount /run/systemd/private. I have no idea how risky this is, but it's less than all of /rub/systemd at least

Comment: On Fedora 38 using this method I get `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.` I guess this is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to user59634's answer:

`-v /run/systemd:/run/systemd` works on fedora 27 and ubuntu 16

But the only socket you need is

`docker run -it --rm -v /run/systemd/private:/run/systemd/private fedora reboot`

You can also use `/run/dbus`, but I like this systemd method more. I do not fully understand how much power you are giving the container, I suspect it is a enough to take over your host. So I would only suggest using this in a container that you wrote, and then communicate with any another container see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662102/4166604).

### Unrelated similar information

Sleeping/suspending/hibernating can be done with only the `-v /sys/power/state:/sys/power/state`, and using `/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep suspend` for example. If you know how to, you can echo a string directly to `/sys/power/state`, for example `echo mem > /sys/power/state` [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/states.txt) for more explanation of the different options you get from `cat /sys/power/state`

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -d --name network_monitor --net host --restart always --privileged --security-opt apparmor=unconfined  --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN \
-v /proc:/proc \
$IMAGE_URI
```

docker container must be granted enough permission to mount `/proc`

Comment: I get "Running in chroot, ignoring request.". does not work.