# Is it possible to shut down the host machine by executing a command on one of its docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a host machine which has one docker container. The container is active and running a particular service. On meeting a particular condition, I want to remove the container and shut down the machine also. Is it possible to do so?
I am planning to modify the code which runs the service to handle the shutting down of the machine? Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: A container with the `privileged` flag can shut down the host, by directly making requests of the relevant hardware if need be. Any mechanism to trigger a host shutdown *from a container* that worked without this flag (or other code running on the host) would constitute a bug.

Answer (score 29):

Running a clean shutdown will be dependent on the hosts init system.

To avoid giving the container `--privileged` access and to also avoid installing host specific init tools in your container, you could create an interface to signal the host to shutdown rather than trying to get the container to run the shutdown.

#### An Interface

There's many ways this could be done. A simple starting point could be a mounted volume to share data between the container and host. A file will do for now but you could use a socket, fifo, TCP or any other IPC method you want.

Create a file on the host, say `/var/run/shutdown_signal` and mount the file into your container

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/shutdown_signal:/shutdown_signal whatever
```

Write a string into the file when you want the host to shutdown

```
docker exec $cid sh -c 'echo true > /shutdown_signal'
```

Then you need something running on the host to monitor the file.

A simple script that waits for file changes with `inotifywait`.

```
echo "waiting" > /var/run/shutdown_signal
while inotifywait -e close_write /var/run/shutdown_signal; do 
  signal=$(cat /var/run/shutdown_signal)
  if [ "$signal" == "true" ]; then 
    echo "done" > /var/run/shutdown_signal
    shutdown -h now
  fi
done
```

You could poll the file if `inotifywait` is not available.

```
while sleep 30; do
  signal=$(cat /var/run/shutdown_signal)
  ...
```

### The Horrible Alternative

There is also a more universal, kernel way to trigger an immediate, unclean shutdown in Linux.

```
docker run --privileged busybox \
  sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq; echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger'
```

But this will likely cause more issues for you than it's worth.

Comment: Having an interface between the container and the host, with a script running on the host, makes no sense if the whole thing could be done from the host in a cleaner way.

Comment: @RicardoBranco OP asked to do it from a service running in a container.

Comment: The OP should be told that this is impossible without creating an interface with the host.  But then the interface would be pointless because everything could be done in the host anyway, in a proper way.

Comment: @RicardoBranco What's the proper way to route a message from a service running in a container to the host to trigger a container removal and shutdown?

Comment: By writing to stderr and the host receives it with docker logs, or on file with a mounted volume.

Comment: >>"everything could be done in the host anyway"
This is not true. Why do you think OP uses container in the first place?