# Is it possible to restart a computer from within a docker container on Linux?

Tags: docker

Is it possible to run the command reboot on the host from container ? I tried to mount a volume with the command but without any success.

The idea would be to have a container with some logic inside that I can deploy anywhere on Debian based machines and allow me to reboot a server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to shut down the host machine by executing a command on one of its docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660690/is-it-possible-to-shut-down-the-host-machine-by-executing-a-command-on-one-of-it)

Comment: Yes it's fine. So far I understand it is not possible directly from the container only without having something on the host as well which reduces the interest in this solution